# Height in percent does not work?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why the height in percentage is not working in this code:

`<div style="border-right:1px solid #000; height: 100%;"></div>`.

But when I change the height into pixels it works but my problem is the height is fixed in pixels.

Im using this div element as a vertical ruler/separator.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/jKGUC/5/

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `100%px` won't work. It is either pixels _or_ percent.

Comment: I already changed it to 100% and removed the ';'. but still not working. I updated my link as well. Thanks.

Comment: the 100% in reference to what? to the `<body>` or the menu on the left?

Comment: lol, can't get it to work as it should... I will try again tomorrow, now it's to late

Comment: It's OK. Im also doing my best to figure it out.

Comment: `div`s inside of `td`s is sloppy coding at best... get rid of the `table` layouts if you want to get rid of these kinds of headaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `height: 100%;` to the `table` and to the `td` around the `div` should do the trick. Here's the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jKGUC/9/

Answer (score 7):

The `height: 100%;` style sets the height according to the height of the parent container. If the parent is the body, you also need to specify the height on those elements.

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Still not working but thanks anyway. I'll still try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

if the parent is not "pixel", its children's height are impossible to set "percent"